# Can an electric current be induced in a liquid flowing in region of uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I just wanted to know if there are instances of liquid materials that give rise to currents when they move in a region of constant magnetic field. I am drawing a parallel with the basic example of a “solid” loop moving in a magnetic field. Does the same phenomenon exist for liquids?

Comment: A natural example is given by  the Earth, where the liquid metal in the outer core goes through a magnetic field, which causes an electric current to flow within the liquid metal. See e.g. this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53791/226902 and this cool question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645854/226902

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flow_meter